# expandable dropdown with dynamic data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I simply want this functionality .

---

---

[image]

i.e. autocomplete textbox with expandable dropdown and dropdown selected item put up to auto complete textbox

I made auto complete working fine , but I am not able to make expandable dropdown with dynamic data ,

I have search some post showing example with static data only ..

I have found some jquery plug in for it , this also works for static data

http://www.jqueryscript.net/menu/Lightweight-Popup-Menu-Plugin-For-jQuery-Popr.html

Here is the code what I have tried

```
<head>    
<div class="popr" data-id="demo">Click me</div>
    <div class="popr-box" data-box-id="demo">
     <div >Menu Item 1</div>                    ---fine with static data
     <div >Menu Item 2</div>
    </div>
</head>
```

---

```
$(document).ready(function () {
populate();
}

function populate(){
        $.ajax({
            //.....           
            success: function(states) {
             var $select = $('#demo'); // --dynamic data not binding to demo   
                                          --div 
                $.each(states, function(i, state) {
                    $('<option>', {
                        value: state
                    }).html(state).appendTo($select); });},});}
//this is plugin code 

 $('.popr').popr();


    $('.popr').popr({
        'speed': 200,
        'mode': 'bottom'
    });
```

I need some help that I do I need to do different approach for it , with css or something alse ?

Comment: You have incorrect selector. use `var $select = $("div[data-box-id="demo"]");`

Comment: check my answer. please run snippet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have used incorrect `selector`. You have use like

```js
var $select = $('div[data-box-id="demo"]');

alert($select.html());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<head>    
<div class="popr" data-id="demo">Click me</div>
    <div class="popr-box" data-box-id="demo">
     <div >Menu Item 1</div>                   
     <div >Menu Item 2</div>
    </div>
</head>
```

Comment: @NeerajVerma do you get data in `ajax` `success`?? first of your problem resloved by `selector`

Comment: working fine now , thanks , Can you also tell also to get selected value to textbox

Comment: @NeerajVerma do `$select.val()`

Comment: On which event shuld I post it ?? ............. I tried       $('div[data-box-id="demo"]').change(function () { }); .............

and .............
    $('div[data-id="demo"]').change(function () {}); ..... But it is not working

Comment: I am still looking for 2nd answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101377/discussion-between-parth-trivedi-and-neeraj-verma).

Answer (score 0):

change

```
<div class="popr-box" data-box-id="demo">
```

to

```
<div class="popr-box" id="demo">
```

Comment: on clicking , list item comes with "undefined"

Comment: @Parth Trivedi is right, you use incorrect selector,  so i change 'data-box-id ' to 'id', but 'undefined' may be the problem of datas, you can check "states" or use an array to test.

Comment: Can you  tell also that how on which event should I get get selected value to textbox ..I tried $('div[data-box-id="demo"]').change(function () { }); ............. and ............. $('div[data-id="demo"]').change(function () {}); ..... But it is not working –